# How to stop calling incompatible method in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I encountered this issue while working on my personal project. 
In short, I have 2 polymorphic classes: `base` and `derived` and a function `caller()` that tries to call a method present in `derived` but not in the `base`. The `derived` class also has a variable not present in the base which is used inside that method.

If the `caller()` is called with the argument of type `base *` it will fail with `Segmentation fault`, since it cannot find the variable used in the method in the `base` class, as seen in the example below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


class base {
    virtual void someFunction() { /* Do something */ }
};


class derived : public base {
public:
    void someFunction() override { /* Do something else */ }

    void functionNotInBase() {  // Do something base can't
        std::cout << variableNotInBase << std::endl;
    };

private:
    int variableNotInBase {5};
};


void caller(base *p) {
    dynamic_cast<derived *>(p)->functionNotInBase();
}


int main() {
    auto d = new derived();
    auto b = new base();

    caller(d);  // Ok, pointer to derived
    caller(static_cast<base *>(d));  // Ok, pointer to derived (cast to base)
    caller(b);  // Error, classes are not compatible (no variable in base to be printed)

    delete b;
    delete d;
}
```

My question now is: how to stop the `caller()` from calling the method on incompatible type (everything not inherited from `derived`)? The `caller()` may do nothing in this case but it should not fail with `Segmentation fault`.

One more problem is that I'm developing for Arduino which doesn't have the type support library with `typeid()` function that could check the pointer type at the runtime.

**Thank you.**

Comment: Have you tried the answer you accepted? Just curious. If there is no rtti support, dynamic_cast should not work either, and it doesn't work for a lot of people on Arduino. So I wonder how it works for you.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. This was more of a question about `dynamic_cast` in general but yes, that solution does **not** work on an Arduino, so virtual base class function seems like the only way in my particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check result of `dynamic_cast`, you currently can (and do) deference `nullptr`:

```
void caller(base *p) {
    auto der = dynamic_cast<derived *>(p);

    if (der) der->functionNotInBase();
}
```

Comment: Please don't do things like that. Dynamic cast is not meant for this.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic cast is a band aid. Never use dynamic cast in business logic of object oriented code. If you think you need it, you have a design problem, and it will bite you down the road.

You have this logic:

```
if object is derived
    call derived method
else
    do nothing
```

**This logic should be moved to a virtual function of the base class**.

```
  class base {
      virtual void do_businesst() { }
  };

  class derived : public base {
      void do_business() override {
         functionNotInBase();
      }
  };
```